# Why does Pages all the sudden need permission to print?

Tags: printing, pages

I just tried to print something in Pages and got this:

[image: pages print permissions]

The printer *was* paused, and I was asked to resume it, but *this*? Why?

Pages 4.3 on OS X 10.8.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open keychain and find Pages.

Right click and click on Get info

in the you can set the access and change it to what you need.

this is an example only

[image]